# How do I update a grid in my XAML UI?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using C# WPF, VS2013.

Here is my `MainWindow` class definition:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void addData(){
    //this is the method I want to access
    }
...
}
```

I want to use the `addData` method from another class. Theoretically it should be something like:

```
public class DataEntry
{
     public void randomMethod()
     {
         MainWindow.addData(); //this doesn't work - the addData method can not be accessed
     }
}
```

If I do it like this:

```
public class DataEntry
{
     public void randomMethod()
     {
         MainWindow mw = new MainWindow()
         mw.addData();
     }
}
```

I can access it, but then I end up with two `MainWindow`s.

If I change the method definition of `addData()` to `public static void addData()` then it **can** be accessed from the outer class (`DataEntry`), but then I can not access my `TextBox` from the `addData()` method.

Comment: I take it that you're relatively new to programming in C#, and perhaps to programming in general. While your question is certainly appropriate here, may I also suggest that you look for a beginners' tutorial online?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing your UI from a non-UI class like that to begin with.  The business logic should need no knowledge of the UI to do its job.

Comment: Well, I need to somehow add data to my `DataGrid` which is available only from the `MainWindow` class. Unless there is a way to access the `DataGrid` from a method in the `DataEntry` class - I did not find any.

Comment: Silverlight/WPF works on their own fundamentals. Data Binding, Dependency Property, Resources, DataContext, INotifyPropertyChanged interface and many more. if you understand these concepts, this could be trivial task for you. Though, do you really need help with this, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a reasonable intuitive assumption about how you'd do it, and it would be correct in a lot of environments, but not in XAML. In XAML you do things very differently: You put your data in something the grid knows how to examine, you show that to the grid, and the grid handles the details of populating itself.

It's declarative. You say what you want: "I want this list of stuff to be in the grid". Let the grid fiddle around with incrementing `i` for the millionth time.

The data that goes in the grid should be in an ObservableCollection (we'll call it GridItems), which should be a public property of your view model class. If you don't have a view model, it's time to write one -- we'll call it MainWindowViewModel. It doesn't necessarily have to do a whole lot. That's where the data lives, and the functions that load and save it. The View -- your MainWindow -- is in charge of showing the data to the user, and exposing menu items or buttons to load and save etc. But MainWindow just exposes those controls, and binds them to Commands exposed by the view model. MainWindow knows what the commands are called, but he has no knowledge of what they mean.

The MainWindowViewModel instance is assigned to MainWindow.DataContext. The DataGrid's ItemsSource property should be bound to GridItems.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" ...>
    <!-- columns, etc. -->
</DataGrid>
```

When somebody adds or removes items on viewmodel.GridItems, the grid will be notified and will update itself accordingly.

This is the standard way things are done in XAML, and once you get used to it, it's pretty slick.

For the view model to expose lists of things is easy: Just use ObservableCollection. For non-list properties, you'll need to inherit your view model class from INotifyPropertyChanged, and implement that interface (see Google for that, it's not a big deal). So say you have a CurrentFileName property in your view model...

```
private String _currentFileName;
public String CurrentFileName {
    get { return _currentFileName; }
    set {
        _currentFileName = value;
        //  If you've implemented this properly, this will send out a 
        //  notification that this property has changed. Any binding  
        //  in MainWindow that's bound to this property will get that 
        //  and act on it. 
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentFileName");
    }
}
```

Also, I'd like to concur that a tutorial would be a good idea, if you're new enough to programming that creating a new instance of MainWindow seems like a plausible way to update the old one.

Comment: But... I want to add items (rows with data) to my `DataGrid`. I do not care about updating it. I simply want to add data to one `DataGrid` from three different classes. My only problem is that I do not know how to "tell" the program to "use my `DataGrid` that is created in `MainWindow`".

Comment: If you bind that GridItems collection to the grid's ItemsSource property, and add items to GridItems, they will be added to the grid. If the content visible in the grid changes (for example, it displays a newly added row), the grid has been updated. Updating means it changes the stuff it shows. You DO care about updating it. "Updating" is the term for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I finally got it! Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioPetrov Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having your business logic know about, access, and manipulate the UI based on some value that it computes, just return the value from the method instead.  Leave it up tot he UI that calls that class to take the return value from the method and do whatever it needs to do with it, such as setting a textbox value.

In addition to simply being easier, this has the advantage of greatly reducing the coupling of your application.  Your business logic now doesn't *need* to be used with this particular UI.  You could create an entirely different presentation of this logic without needing to duplicate it; you can test it without needing to access the UI; it can be written, maintained, and reasoned about *in isolation* rather than complicating it with a bunch of UI logic.